# Unable to launch javascript function from html onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sure this is a very simple question for you, but i just don't get it.

I have some php code that displays a table, in which i have a div that onclik should trigger a function to change the clicked element background color.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class='modRequiredLink' onclick='test();'>
   <div id='animated-example' class='animatedSlide'></div>
</div>
```

Here's the function:

```
function test() {
    $(".modRequiredLink").click(function (event) {
        $(this).find("#animated-example").toggleClass("red");;
    });
}
```

Now, like this it works but it needs two click to be triggered, while if i change the function to just this:

```
function test() {
        $(this).find("#animated-example").toggleClass("red");;
}
```

it doesn't work anymore...

Why? any advice? thanks in advance

Comment: You have extra semi-colons you should clean up - `onclick='test();` and `...toggleClass("red");;`

Comment: Because `$(this)` is not referring to what you think it is referring to

Comment: Why not just use  `$("#animated-example").toggleClass("red");`  ?

Comment: Either use element `onclick` or use jquery binding, pick one stick with it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first snippet runs the `test()` function which only *binds* a handler to be invoked upon `click` event, but it isn't actually invoking it.

Your second snippet is not working because `this` is not referring to the element being clicked (but to the global `window`). Try this instead:

```
<div class='modRequiredLink' onclick='test(this);'>

function test(elm) {
    $(elm).find("#animated-example").toggleClass("red");
}
```

Comment: perfect. It works as I expected. Thank you very much! I'll accept this in 9 minutes :)

Comment: @Nick: Learn more about how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this , http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: Thank you, i was about to ask for some resource to look at. Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
function test() {
        $("#animated-example").toggleClass("red");
}
```

Not everything has to be tied to $(this).